# how to add retrial logic for failed jobs in cronjob?

Tags: terminal, cron, jupyterhub

I have scheduled a cronjob with the below syntax and it works well. The code is in the below. But I need add a function saying if the job failed, retry that notebook after 4 hours.

I didn't find a solution in google. Can anyone help me take a look?

Thank you very much.

```
PATH=/opt/tljh/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

## test
05 23 * * * papermill ~/a.ipynb ~/a_output.ipynb
05 23 * * * papermill ~/b.ipynb ~/b_output.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron does not natively support anything like this. You can potentially wrap your script into a shell script and add a cron job to check at the 4 hour mark:

(assuming your program utilizes error codes)

```
PATH=/opt/tljh/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

## test
05 23 * * * if papermill ~/a.ipynb ~/a_output.ipynb; then rm -f /tmp/job_previously_failed; else  touch /tmp/job_previously_failed; fi
05 03 * * * if [ -f /tmp/job_previously_failed ]; then papermill ~/a.ipynb ~/a_output.ipynb; rm -f /tmp/job_previously_failed; fi
05 23 * * * if ~/b.ipynb ~/b_output.ipynb; then rm -f /tmp/job_previously_failed; else  touch /tmp/job_previously_failed; fi
05 03 * * * if [ -f /tmp/job_previously_failed ]; then ~/b.ipynb ~/b_output.ipynb; rm -f /tmp/job_previously_failed; fi
```

Highly recommend you move these into separate script files and not write all this inline in cron. It'll get messy fast.

Comment: Bravo. My unsung hero!